# Excel concatenate strings including if else statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, concatenation

I have this table

```
      A      B       C       D
 1   User | priv1 | priv2 | priv3
 2   test |   y   |   n   |   n   
 3   more |   n   |   y   |   n
```

and so on and I want to generate db2 commands from that.

```
 ="GRANT "&(IF B2="y", B1, "")& ", "&(IF C2="y", C1, "" )& ", "&(IF D2="y", D1, "" )&" on DATABSE TO USER "&A2&";"
```

should there for be

```
 GRANT priv1 ON DATABASE TO USER test;
```

However I can't get those IF parts to work.

Any idea? I tried many syntaxes but none get it to work. Google wasn't my friend either.

EXCEL 365 on Windows 10

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want multiple "y"'s in cells you can use textJoin function

like this:

```
="GRANT "&TEXTJOIN(", ";1;IF(B2="y";$B$1;"");IF(C2="y";$C$1;"");IF(D2="y";$D$1;""))&" on DATABASE TO USER "&A2&";"
```

this formula will place commas if needed

here is working example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UmuNpkKQz4KWPJIqT8j8iFO1GB5_J119

**UPDATE:**
if you are able to modify source table better to modify it to this:

```
      A      B       C       D
 1   User | priv1 |       |     
 2   test | priv2 |       |      
 3   more | priv3 |       |   
 4   other| priv1 | priv3 |
```

then formula will be more simple like this:

```
="grant "&TEXTJOIN(", ";1;B2:D2)&" on database to user "&A2&";"
```

here is the example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IiSmT3OYLpxMvaeG0KYgK17ZYengWxWu

Comment: I get the #NAME? if I use that

Comment: could you please share file?

Answer (score 0):

Brackets after the IF

```
 ="GRANT "&IF(B2="y", B1, "")& ", "&IF(C2="y", C1, "" )& ", "&IF(D2="y", D1, "" )&" on DATABASE TO USER "&A2&";"
```

EDIT: And quotes aropund the text in B1,C1, D1 and A2

```
="GRANT "&IF(B2="y", "'"&B1&"'", "")& ", "&IF(C2="y", "'"&C1&"'", "" )& ", "&IF(D2="y","'"&D1&"'", "" )&" on DATABASE TO USER '"&A2&"';"
```

Comment: It works for me - what's the error? - did you copy and paste the formula?

Comment: Try a semicolon as seperator symbol?

Comment: Where should I put the semicolon

Comment: sorry - I forgot to test this with your actual data so i didn't notice the text needing quote marks